# Fetch all records from all table in the same database

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to render all records from all tables in the sample database,  below query is returning all the tables record counts. but i want all records from all tables in the sample database.

```
SELECT   TableName = o.name,
         Rows = max(i.rows)
FROM     sysobjects o
         INNER JOIN sysindexes i
           ON o.id = i.id
GROUP BY o.name
ORDER BY Rows DESC
```

Comment: Then `mysql` or `sql server`. I think `sql server`.

Comment: There's no `sysobjects` table in Mysql, so this is SQL Server. Mysql tag removed, as no indication was given that this needs to be cross platform...

Comment: Could you post an example output?

Comment: Why do you need this for?

Comment: Do you need the results in 1 table? This will apply only if you have a couple of tables with exactly the same columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an undocumented(*) stored procedure to run a query against each table in the database:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'select * from ?'
```

This will return one result set for each table. If you want the table name as a separate column:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'select ''?'' as TableName,* from ?'
```

There's no easy way to get just a single result set since, in general, the columns of all of the tables in a database will not be compatible with each other.

---

(*) Hopefully, the danger here is obvious. It's undocumented, so it's possible that it will go away or change based on any servicing operations applied to SQL Server. On the other hand, I doubt they will ever remove it, and it doesn't have any special magic inside. For belt and braces, you might want to copy the procedure into your own database under a different name, and then you can rely on it not being changed.